# XML schema cardinality

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

Given the following xml data model, how would I specify in the xsd that the dept data model can have multiple employee nodes, but atleast one of them must have the `<isSupervisor></isSupervisor>` element.
So, in other words, the `<isSupervisor></isSupervisor>` is not required for all employees but at least one employee should have it.

```
<Dept>
  <Employee>
    <name></name>
    <title></title>
    <isSupervisor></isSupervisor>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <name></name>
    <title></title>
    <isSupervisor></isSupervisor>
  </Employee>
  <deptname></deptname>
  <deptid></deptid>
<Dept>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need **XSD 1.1** to declare assertions based on type content.

In the declaration for `Employee`, `isSupervisor` should be declared as optional:

```
<xs:element name="Employee">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="isSupervisor" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

In the declaration for `Dept`, the `xs:assert` expression should always be true:

```
<xs:element name="Dept">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Employee" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="deptname"/>
            <xs:element name="deptid"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <!-- true if at least one Employee/isSupervisor exists -->
        <xs:assert test="Employee/isSupervisor"/> 
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```